# Laravel Forge - Complete List of Past Deployment Logs

Tags: laravel, forge

When using the `Forge` interface, you can always view the `Latest Deployment Log`. What I'm trying to reach, is the complete list of past deployment logs. Is that possible? The log files' location also works as I have SSH access to the actual server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in [Laracasts Forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/laravel-forge-complete-list-of-past-deployment-logs)

The logs reside in `~/.forge` directory. You have to look for `~/.forge/provision-*` files. For each `provision` you'll find a `.sh` and a `.output` file. As the names suggest, first one includes the commands that were run and the second one includes the output of all those commands.